# Materialize dropdown options

Tags: javascript, slim

I want to use the options from here:

http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html#options *(The docs don't say so much).*

> My app is a rails app that use the materialize gem with the asset
>   pipeline.

My code now looks like this:

```
ul#dropdown1.dropdown-content.z-depth-0
    li
      a Profile settings
    li
      a payments
a.dropdown-button.btn-large.btn-flat.waves-effect.menu_trigger href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1"
 i.material-icons menu

javascript:
  var elem = document.querySelector('.menu_trigger');
  var instance = M.Dropdown.init(elem, {
    coverTrigger: false,
    constrainWidth: false,
  });
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: make it work the options, i want to use the options, it's on the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solved!**

Finally like it says here http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/dropdown.html#options

Solved where it says:

> To use these inline you have to add them as data attributes. If you
>   want more dynamic control, you can define them using the jQuery plugin
>   below.

*So then, with something like this:*

```
a.dropdown-button.btn-large.btn-flat.waves-effect href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1" data-beloworigin="true"
  i.material-icons menu
```

**Done what i wanted**

Answer (score 5):

In practice, using the `data` attribute isn't always the best way. Options can (or rather should be, correct me if I'm wrong) passed the following way:

```
// native javascript way
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var dropdown1 = document.querySelector('.simple-dropdown');
    var dropdownOptions = {
        'closeOnClick': true,
        'hover':true
    }
    var instanceDropdown1 = M.Dropdown.init(dropdown1, dropdownOptions);
});

// Initializing the jQuery way
$(".simple-dropdown").dropdown(
{
    'closeOnClick': true,
    'hover': true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find directly in Materialize docs, but by trial and error I found this javscript code is working fine. It looks like an expected options variable should be an Object with property "dropdownOptions" with assigned another Object with properties listed in docs.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var options = {
    dropdownOptions: {
        alignment: 'right',
        hover: true
    }
}
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
});
```